# javascript regex to find html tags

Tags: javascript

I have a string like below.

```
<b><span style="font-size:10px;font-family:arial;color:0000FF;">test</span><i>italic and     bold</b>italic</i><u>underline</u>
```

I need to validate if the string contains only these 4 html tags and their corresponding end tags.

I need to give warning message when other than the above tags are present.

Please let me know how to do using javascript regex.

Note: the 4 tags can be in any order in the string

Comment: Trying to parse HTML with regex is generally not a good idea, especially not if you want to check for validity of the code you're inspecting.

Comment: Where is your code?...

Comment: Note you have interleaved `</b>` and `</i>` tags in that string. That may be part of the challenge, though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: if not in regex how else to do?

Comment: @user, good question. You cannot use an XML parser because your string is not a well-formed XML fragment. You *could* use an HTML parser but, again, the interleaved closing tags will most probably be compensated somehow, and the resulting tree will not be equivalent to the original string.